# Sharing Memcache with PHP and Python

Tags: php, python, memcached, flags

I am trying to share a Memcache key between Python and PHP. Python writes the key and PHP reads it. I am using the Cakephp framework, with php-pecl-memcache (not php-pecl-memcached), and the python-memcache all python library.

Python:

```
  mc = memcache.Client( ["127.0.0.1:11211"])
  key = "key1"
  value = 1323779849
  mc.set(key, value)
```

PHP:

```
  echo Cache::read('key1', 'memcached');
```

PHP can't read the variable, I get weird "MemcachePool::get() [http://php.net/memcachepool.get]: Failed to uncompress data" errors; I suspect it has to do with memcached flags that are set differently in each library.

This is what happens when I telnet to memcached:

Python sets key:

```
 get key1
 VALUE key1 1 12
 1323779849
 .
 END
```

PHP sets key:

```
 get key1
 VALUE key 1 0 12
 1323779849
 END
```

- Is there a way to override these flags and just 'do your own thing'?
- Are there php/python memcache libraries that play better together?
- Alternatively, is there a simple way to create a common memory space between python/php?

Comment: thanks Will, but all I am trying to do is share a simple data type, either an int or a string, so there is no need to serialize, pickle or even compress. And I would rather not write to a file because of the performance impact although yes, that would do the trick.

Comment: If you've tried integers and strings I don't think you can get away from using (consistent) serialization.

Comment: You might missing some points, memcache has an option to compress and serialize data (even is just a single byte). This is more for internal usage. I guess python API is enable compression by default, while your PHP api did not enable it by default. You did not mention what exactly API you used for memcache, So, I guess nobody can really dig the documentation and provide an insight answer.

Comment: Thanks Ajreal, but in this case it was simpler because all I was trying to do was store an Integer and neither PHP or Python were trying to compress the data. It really comes down to PHP and Python using different flags to represent the same thing. I have explained all in my Answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Lot's of stuff wasn't working as expected.

1. One problem is that php and python use different flags to do different things. 
   Not a problem in an all-python or all-php solution, but for inter-environment communication a real problem. A useful resource is http://www.hjp.at/zettel/m/memcached_flags.rxml, which shows that python-memcache flags long integer as '2', which php-memcache does not understand, hence the *compression error*. I amended python-memcache to include a 'flag-override' in the set function. This variable simply forces a particular flag irrespective of what python memcache thinks it ought to be. This allowed me to re-flag Int from 2 to 0. I will prob branch the current version of python-memcache and submit it to Github. This allowed me to force the python long int flag (2) to something php would understand (0).
2. CakePhp prior to 1.3.3 stores all keys in memcached with an additional key_expires key, flagged as 768, etc, etc. Without this additional key it cannot find the key you are looking for. Thankfully this behaviour was dumped in later Cakephp version (I simply upgraded to 1.3.13) and it works well now.

Comment: One other thing: I could have also switched to Mysql MEMORY/HEAP table type and achieved the same thing.

Comment: Compression errors are easy to avoid using pylibmc PROPERLY compiled and flagged. The one of the most in-depth bugs is the string key value. When you're using set() method ALWAYS use str() representation for the key name AND the value. Both. Or you will discover that there's a garbage of 7 bytes before the actual string content. Beware =)

Answer (score 0):

When you put something via python memcached, it's probably pickled. So PHP cannot unpickle it. I would try to use some kind of very basic type maybe ctypes? Maybe raw strings?

Comment: I've tried raw strings and straight integers, neither work :(

Comment: One more thing. In the past I used session and session cookie to communicate between php/python. There is one drawback. It's depended to machine, so if you have multi cluster technology it may be awful. Otherwise it's quite simple. You can keep session on your hdd in file, data can be jsoned as transfered as string. It's not very flexible solution but it worked for me once.

Comment: One more thing, you can try to use cmemache instead of memcache, it might help. However I doubt. You can try to use some fast db to your communication, something like lets say noSql (Riak, CouchDB, etc) or SqlLite.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, using PHP and pymemcache. I serialized Python dictionary with https://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.serialize/ and wrote that to memcache. PHP side also had it's own way of storing into memcache, and memcache values written by PHP and Python seemed to be the same, but PHP couldn't read Python set value properly, so it puzzled me a lot. PHP read it as a String, being unable to deserialize it / convert it to an Array. Then I got to read memcache values using netcat, like this:

```
echo -e 'get my-key\r' | nc 192.168.1.17 11211
```

Python set value returned:

```
VALUE my-key 0 1460
```

, while PHP set value had:

```
VALUE my-key 1 1460
```

Not knowing how to deal with these flags, I simply used this - on PHP side, if I got a String "a:{s:6..." instead of an Array, I used PHP's unserialize() method to make it an Array and it worked.