# Cache updated every hour-where to store it?

Tags: php, python, caching, storage

I have a python script that generates data(every hour), to be later read by a PHP web page. Where should I store the data - in a database, in a file, or somewhere else? There will be something close to 100-200KB/user of data. Which will be a beter solution? The data is not plain text, which means I'll have to use json or xml to store it.

Example data:(XML is easy to read, don't blame me!)

```
    <item uid="1">
<title>Malala's voice stronger, not silenced</title>
<rating>3</rating>
<date>Wednesday, May 8, 2013 2:03 PM</date>
<text>The attack was meant to silence the outspoken teenager who dared to defy the Taliban's ban against girls in school. Instead, it only made Malala's voice more powerful. After a school year that started with a shooting, Malala now eyes a summer of speaking at the U.N., telling her story in a new book and amplifying the issue of girls education.    </text>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your data? So that we know what kind of data you want to store? In some cases a file could be best, but in most of the cases a db will do best. Maybe a combination? So please give us some insight :) (if it is a really long text, shorten it with `(...)` and tell us how many kb's that column contains).

Comment: I'll edit it in in a sec.

Comment: Note: you said you could use json or xml. Think about serialized data as well when you are considering filestorage. I have noticed unserializing faster than decoding json. But encoding json is faster than serializing. My point is: where do you need the speed? Writing or reading?

Comment: I need it on reading, so I can store it serialized... So yeah... But.. database or files?

Comment: Personally I would go for a database. Just because of the easy access. But check out [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17380096/1110760). He has a valid point. So I guess I won't be much of help here :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the scale of your web application. If it's going to be fairly small and not grow that big over time, the file system would be fine. It's a great option because it's so simple. Very easy to read/write files.

If you want something more serious, you can go for a distributed cache and start it with just one node running locally.

Lots of options there:

- Redis (http://redis.io/)
- Couchbase (http://www.couchbase.com/)
- App Fabric for Windows machines (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric)

Lots of databases in general support JSON these days:

- MongoDB (http://www.mongodb.org/)
- Riak (http://basho.com/riak/)
- CouchDB (http://couchdb.apache.org/)

I would definitely go with JSON as your serialized data format.

Answer (score 0):

Generally querying a database is expensive and if you eventually scale your application you will get problems as every time you need to read the data you also need to query the database. Which will cause reading the data to fail.

There is a technique to avoid this. It's called memcache. A good intro to memcache can be found at the [Udacity course](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253) it's lesson 6. There was also [another post at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490312/sharing-memcache-with-php-and-python) which explained how they successfully shared the memcache with the languages python and php.

Comment: memcache was my first idea too, unfortunately it's not an option :(

Comment: Yes, why is it not an option @user2534511?